# Why not $\rho^{2}=T^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$ as an effective mass density (squared ) in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mass, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Why not $\rho^{2}=T^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$
  as an effective mass density (squared) in general relativity? It's covariant, and as far as I can tell is zero for any electromagnetic field tensor.

\begin{align*}\rho &=\sqrt{T^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}}\\  &=\sqrt{T_{\,\rho}^{\mu}g^{\rho\nu}T_{\,\nu}^{\sigma}g_{\sigma\mu}}\\ &=\sqrt{(T_{\,\rho}^{\mu}e_{\mu}e^{\rho})(T_{\,\nu}^{\sigma}e^{\nu}e_{\sigma})}\end{align*}

They're all dummy variables so:

\begin{align} &=\sqrt{(T_{\,\rho}^{\mu}e_{\mu}e^{\rho})^{2}}\\ &=e_{\mu}T_{\,\rho}^{\mu}e^{\rho}\end{align}
 Best of all, it also makes sense for any physical stress energy tensor I throw its way. It appears to reduce to the Komar mass when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The quantity $T^{\mu\nu} T_{\mu\nu}$ appears in the TOSEC (trace of square energy condition). The quantity can become negative, for instance in the stress energy tensor of the Unruh vacuum in the Schwarzschild metric, hence I would not recommend taking its square root.

Comment: wouldn't the negative Unruh vacuum be a manifestation of gravitational energy, in your example caused by the Swarschild metric, whereas I'm talking about calculating mass as the source of the gravitational field. I'm staying within standard general relativity, no massive gravity theories here. To put it another way, the Unruh energy your mentioning would necessarily be on the other side of the Einstein equation, with the curvature terms.

Comment: No, this corresponds to the vacuum expectation value of a scalar field.

Comment: how is it a tensor quantity then, as Unruh radiation will vanish in a particular frame, which makes it very similar to the pseudotensors of gravitational energy. Honestly I'm just super curious

Comment: The Unruh vacuum isn't the same as Unruh radiation.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't come across that yet, but for this I was sticking to purely classical general relativity. Are you aware of a non quantum violation of this? It actually has some bearing, as I was introducing all quantum effects for a project via a separate avenue. Thank you, I appreciate your insight.

Comment: This can be done in purely classical general relativity, if you don't impose any restrictions on the stress energy tensor. If you have $T_{00} = \rho$, $T_{aa} = p_a$ and $T_{0a} = f_a$, then you will get negative values for a stress energy tensor with $$\rho^2 + \sum_i p_i^2 - 2\sum_i f_i^2 < 0$$

Comment: I was trying to stick with physical stress energy tensors, but its very late, so ill sleep on it

Comment: Well then the question is what is a physical stress energy tensor

Comment: I was interested in finding quantities analogous to Komar mass that would perservere in no stationary spacetimes. (plants, stars and the like) Still though, you got me thinking. The Unruh vacuum expectation value is an average put back into a stress energy tensor. The same can be done with gravitational energies as the pseudotensor still yields covariant quantities upon integration that can be similarly wielded. I can't help but think they're the same. Thank you  for the stimulation!

Comment: The only issue I have with your answer, is that for :

$$\rho=e_{\mu}T^{\mu}\,_{\nu}e^{\nu}$$
 

to be imaginary as per your objection, the Stress Energy tensor would have to have at least one imaginary component to begin with. While there is a lot of leeway on defining stress-energy tensors, I don't think an imaginary one is ok.

Comment: This is not a scalar. Remember that the real formula is $T^\mu_\nu e_\mu^a e^\nu_b T^\alpha_\beta e_\alpha^b e^\beta_a$

Comment: Its a (1,1) tensor dotted into a basis vector and one form. It has to be a scalar. Perhaps I should have written it in script, the T isn't the component but the actual tensor. As per usual Einstein summation is implied.

Comment: I just noticed that you decomposed into a tetrad frame. Doesn't this go like:

$$e^{\mu}\Longrightarrow e_{\,a}^{\mu}\gamma^{a}$$
 

I could be wrong, it's been a while since I've played with tetrads

Comment: $$T_{\,\nu}^{\mu}e_{a}^{\nu}\gamma^{a}e_{\mu}^{b}\gamma_{b} $$